# Java EE application under jboss7 using https

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I have a Java EE application deployed under jboss 7 and I want to use https

I modified standalone.xml

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="8443"/>
            <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
                <ssl key-alias="ads-credentials" password="esprit" certificate-key-file="D:\server-keytool.jks" protocol="TLS" verify-client="false"/>
            </connector>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

but when I test I have this error :

```
.........
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1649) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1206) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593) [jsse.jar:1.6]
```

I generate the certificate using this commande :

**keytool -genkey -alias ads-credentials -keyalg RSA –keystore server-keytool.jks**

after serach I think that I should **import certificate into jvm** but I didn't know how can I make this config

I use **jdk1.6.0_25**

**Updated :**

I try with this solution :

C:\javatools\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\security>keytool -import -alias ads-credentials
 -keystore D:\server-keytool.jks -trustcacerts -file cacerts

but I have this error :

```
C:\javatools\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\security>keytool -import -alias ads-credentials
 -keystore D:\server-keytool.jks -trustcacerts -file cacerts
Tapez le mot de passe du Keystore :
erreur keytool : java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.io.IOException: D
erInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
```

the password that I use is the same which is used to create the certificate : **test**

this is the information of my certificate :

```
    C:\javatools\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\security>keytool -list -v -keystore D:\server-k
    eytool.jks
    Tapez le mot de passe du Keystore :

    Type Keystore : JKS
    Fournisseur Keystore : SUN

    Votre Keystore contient 1 entrÚe(s)

    Nom d'alias : ads-credentials
    Date de crÚation : 8 janv. 2014
    Type d'entrÚeá: PrivateKeyEntry
    Longueur de cha¯ne du certificat : 1
    Certificat[1]:
    PropriÚtaireá: CN=alen dumas, OU=ing, O=dao, L=france, ST=nice, C=216
    ╔metteurá: CN=alen dumas, OU=ing, O=dao, L=france, ST=nice, C=216
    NumÚro de sÚrieá: 52cd6102
    Valide duá: Wed Jan 08 15:30:26 CET 2014 auá: Tue Apr 08 16:30:26 CEST 2014
   Empreintes du certificatá:
         MD5á:  E7:A2:8D:8E:51:2E:FC:44:DB:22:3E:BF:8F:D4:81:88
         SHA1á: 05:37:72:10:88:0B:08:8E:FA:05:60:54:48:61:D9:B3:6D:70:A9:69
         Nom de l'algorithme de signatureá: SHA1withRSA
         Versioná: 3


*******************************************
*******************************************

C:\javatools\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\security>
```

Comment: This may be helpful https://support.quovadisglobal.com/KB/a402/how-do-i-install-an-ssl-certificate-into-jboss.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="<ketstore path>"` in VM arguments.